# awk command to extract password from a conf file

Tags: awk

My conf file has the below data

```
DB_CONNECT=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2375/dbname
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=1234
```

and my awk cmd to extract password

```
awk '/^DB_PASS/{print $1}' /pathtofile/dbsettings.conf
```

But the awk cmd is returning whole line of `DB_PASS=1234`. How can I get just pswd `1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk -F= '$1=="DB_PASS" {print $2}' /pathtofile/dbsettings.conf
```

with `F=` we set the separator to `=`. With `$1=="DB_PASS"` we check if the first field is the string `"DB_PASS"`. If it is, we print the second field which must be the password.

Answer (score 2):

Set the field separator to `=` and print the second field:

```
awk -F= '/^DB_PASS/{print $2}' /pathtofile/dbsettings.conf
```